# C++: How to test compile errors to check constraints

Tags: c++, testing, template-meta-programming

I wrote constraints on C++ type using templates.
Now I want to test them in my test suite, in order to notice when the behavior breaks.

Think about `Field` class like this.

```
template <size_t Size>
class Field {
  template<size_t Offset, size_t Count>
  Field<Count> SubString(typename std::enable_if<(Size >= Offset + Count)>::type* = 0) const {
    return Field<Count>(data_.substr(Offset, Count));
  }
}
```

`Field<5>("abcde").SubString<3,4>()` does not compile, because `enable_if` condition fails.
I am looking for a way to check that.

I came up with writing a script to actually compile that expression and check return value, but I prefer to complete in C++.
The compiler is `g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911`. Compiler dependent methods are welcome.

Comment: something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/525219183e8017cb) ?

Comment: Yes. Good technique. What `void()` is for? It seems not required.

Comment: The `void()` in the middle? It is required so that some possible overload of `operator,` for type returned from `SubString` and taking `true_type` will not mess up the result. it just separates two types making sure they will not interact

Comment: That is not required when `operator,` is not overloaded, but guard for that case, right?

Comment: yes, it just protects from that corner case when someone adds `std::false_type operator,(Field<N>, std::true_type)` or something similar

Comment: Understand completely. Thanks!

Comment: like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c32125c1178843c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "prefer to complete in C++"

I'm not aware of any *general-purpose* way to do this with any compiler.  For your very specific example you could hack something up - e.g. a `SubString` overload that would match when enable_if fails, and static assert on the returned type's size.

But for more complex testing, it's normal to have a test "system" that compiles and runs various C++ programs with a variety of data, sometimes ensuring they terminate normally, other times that they can't be compiled etc..  IMHO, you might as well start working on this rather than convoluted hackery for a specific test, as it will prove more useful and flexible longer term.